# Fatal error: Call to a member function getUserStateFromRequest() on a non-object in administrator\components\com_jquarks\models\quizzes.php on line 60

Tags: joomla2.5

i am using joomla 2.5 and i want to create some tests for my students, so that's why i just downloaded JQuarks plugin and installed. But when i go to Components/JQuarks through administration panel it shows me this error!!

**Fatal error: Call to a member function getUserStateFromRequest() on a non-object in administrator\components\com_jquarks\models\quizzes.php on line 60**

So, i go to on line 60 .
Here's the code:

```
    function getQuizzes() 
{
    if (empty( $this->_quizzes )) 
    {
        global $mainframe ;

        $context    = 'com_jquarks.quizzes.list.' ;
        $limit      = $mainframe->getUserStateFromRequest('global.list.limit', 'limit', $mainframe->getCfg('list_limit'), 'int' );
        $limitstart = $mainframe->getUserStateFromRequest( $context.'limitstart', 'limitstart', 0, 'int') ;

        $this->_filter_order        = $mainframe->getUserStateFromRequest( $context.'filter_order', 'filter_order', 'title', 'cmd' );
        $this->_filter_order_Dir    = $mainframe->getUserStateFromRequest( $context.'filter_order_Dir', 'filter_order_Dir', '', 'word' );

        $orderby = '' ;

        if($this->_filter_order_Dir) {
            $orderby = ' ORDER BY '.$this->_filter_order.' '.$this->_filter_order_Dir ;
        }

        $query = ' SELECT quizzes.*, g.name AS groupname' .
        ' FROM #__jquarks_quizzes AS quizzes' .
        ' LEFT JOIN #__groups AS g ON g.id = quizzes.access_id' .
        $orderby ;

        $total = $this->_getListCount($query) ; 

        jimport('joomla.html.pagination') ;
        $this->_pageNav = new JPagination( $total, $limitstart, $limit ) ;

        $this->_db->setQuery($query) ;          
        $this->_quizzes = $this->_getList( $query, $this->_pageNav->limitstart, $this->_pageNav->limit );
        if ($this->_db->getErrorNum()) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return $this->_quizzes ;
}
```

Please help to fix this problem!!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a problem. Problem is the version of the Jquarks plugin was 0.2.4 and my joomla's version is 2.5. So i looked up from internet ,JQuarks 0.2.4 is for joomla 1.5 version not for joomla 2.5 . Then i just downloaded another plugin called ARI Quiz Lite to create some exams for my students. This plugin is for joomla 1.5,2.5 and 3.0 . Now its working.....:)